# Concurrent access to lightweight/(embedded?) SQL database by several applications on the same local machine?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sqlite, sql-server-ce

I am looking for a solution in which several applications on the same machine access one and the same database. Generally the operations are just reads thus I am not interested in having to provide concurrent write access as well.

I checked into SQL Server Express, SQL Server LocalDb, SQL CE, SQLite, MySQL and am not convinced which one is the best solution. I read that SQL CE allows concurrent read access but SQL Server LocalDb does not, which I find very odd given LocalDb is hyped by MS as a version that is very similar in functionality to the SQL Server family and which is supposed to make it easy to later on scale out.

I like to manage 5-10 tables each of which holds less than 5000 rows, so really lightweight content.

I am looking for a solution that meets the following requirements:

- Concurrent read access by several applications on the same machine
- Should be somewhat lightweight. I intend to move all applications within a solution to a different machine later and do not want to have to install a 200mb full blown SQL Server Ex@ress version if possible.
- Should play well with VS2012 express (sqlite and mysql are highly unsupported in that regards, either not supporting EF5 or they do not show up in the server explorer.
- Should be an SQL solution in order to manually update database tables within a management console such as Workbench or Management Studio or other third party app.
- Should work somewhat with EF or other ORM solution. I want to be able to create an entity class and create a database from that or update tables using class objects. Also I want to populate class object collections from table rows without having to go through SQL code.

I target C# in .Net 4.5 and I guess it boils down to the question whether SQL CE is up to the task to allow concurrent reads and how I can load CE data tables and edit and visualize the content in some sort of management console. Also does SQL CE play well with EF5? Any better suggestions?

Comment: Where did you read that LocalDb doesn't support concurrent access? Did you try it?

Comment: @MarcGravell, in pretty much every post on SO that compared LocalDb vs SQL CE, and quite a number posts that deal with issues regarding LocalDb

Comment: interesting; I find that surprising since LocalDb is a separate process, rather than in-proc. Not usually an issue for me, but something to consider, thanks.

Comment: I hear very different statements, one answer (which was accepted and multiple times upvoted) stated that SQL LocalDB basically consists of a few files and only one single process can open them at once.

Comment: Let me find the related questions, I feel more comfortable backing up what I said with facts.

Comment: here is one but there were couple others which I could not immediately find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193746/can-sql-server-express-localdb-be-connected-to-remotely

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking for an opinion, [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html) is my answer.

> We are aware of no other embedded SQL database engine that supports as
> much concurrency as SQLite. SQLite allows multiple processes to have
> the database file open at once, and for multiple processes to read the
> database at once. When any process wants to write, it must lock the
> entire database file for the duration of its update. But that normally
> only takes a few milliseconds. Other processes just wait on the writer
> to finish then continue about their business. Other embedded SQL
> database engines typically only allow a single process to connect to
> the database at once.

- [Entity Framework on SQLite](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.com/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html)
- [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

**Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.5)**

> This setup package is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: "is *an* answer". Very rarely in programming is there ever a "*the* answer" ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell How about *my* answer :-)

Comment: @MarcGravell, what is **your** answer?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, is there only a 32-bit dll for .Net? And in your paste what does it mean you need to "lock the entire database file"?

Comment: @Freddy did you click the link? No; I only pointed that link out because there is only a 32-bit Visual Studio. I forget the platform-specifics on SQLite locking, but basically they're saying only one write to the database can happen at a time. Presumably, that means no one can read during the write as well. Limitations of an embedded database implementation, I suppose.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, and a follow up question: Does that include Visual Studio 2012 Express in regards to design-time tools? Does it play nicely with EF? How does the db show up in DataSource explorer? SQL CE does.

Comment: Yes I did click the link and one of the first things I find is that "Unfortunately, System.Data.SQLite does not support creating databases." -> regarding EF. So why do you prefer SQLite over SQL CE?

Comment: I can live with locks while writing that is the nature of embedded dbs. As long as it supports concurrent reads.

Comment: @Freddy I can only speak to the functionality of SQLite and EF4 in VS 2010 (non-express) (.NET 4.)  As for everything else, I'd suggest you just try and see.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, thanks for your suggestion, I am just afraid its a no-go if sqlite cannot create a database from an entity class, whats then the whole point of support for design time tools and support for EF?

Comment: The whole point is everything but the database creation. Database -> EF entities is done for you. Then you have an EF object model to work with instead of writing SQL queries.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, appreciate your opinion and thanks for your suggestion. I will first have a go at Sql Ce and only if that does not fit the bill will chose to try sqLite. I do not want to bother with SQL syntax just to maintain couple settings and other lightweight tables. For that a two-way entity <-> database tables is what I really appreciate which sqLite does not seem to support

Answer (score 0):

SQL CE Works with EF5 and VS 2012 Express, is very lightweight, supports multiple readers on the same machine, and can be managed in VS Pro+ combined with the SQL Server Compact Toolbox add-in (or standalone) (I am the author)