# Connect localdb from production database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a local db server like:

```
(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB
```

As other questions solution to access to other server from main server is to do something like:

```
myserver.mydatabase.dbo.mytable
```

So I try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB.mydatabase.dbo.mytable
```

But it throws an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

What is the correct way to connect to local server database? Regards

Comment: You have to connect to it from the connection string, not the query which should already be connected to the server. The only higher level available in a connection string is either a database or possibly a linked server.

Comment: Agree, I think you're going to need to setup DB link in order to get this working.  That or import a copy of the table that you want to see in main database (if this suits the need).  But for ongoing connections you will want to set up a linked server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can SQL Server Express LocalDB be connected to remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193746/can-sql-server-express-localdb-be-connected-to-remotely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to connect to a localDB from a different server.
If you need such connections you will be better with installing SQL Server Developer edition on a dev box.