# Uploading my windows form/SQLDataBase to github

Tags: c#, database, github, visual-studio-2015

I have created an application that connects to a SqlDataBase that I created in c# visual studio 2015 using Add->New Item->Service-based Database. I've pushed the app to Github but when my friend tried to run the program he got  this exception :

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections
```

My connection string is : Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\RegisterDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True

Comment: Can you confirm with your friend that he has the Database in his updated code?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection points to your SQL Server Express **LocalDB** instance.

**LocalDB** doesn't allow remote connections, please refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) for more details about usage and limitations.

The issue has been already addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193746/can-sql-server-express-localdb-be-connected-to-remotely) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142987/access-sql-server-express-localdb-from-local-area-network).